# Not able to connect AdSense to Gatsby blog

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, connect, adsense

I've been trying to connect my AdSense account with my Gatsby blog and it seems impossible. AdSense is asking me to place this code between the head tag of my html

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

I've tried gatsby adsense plugins and other things and AdSense keeps telling me the code is not in the website. Since the website is hosted in S3, I downloaded the generated index.html and changed the code and re uploaded it. I think the problem is due to an added attribute called data-checked-head to the script tag, so even though I add the code above, what I see in the browser is this:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" data-checked-head="true"></script>
```

If this code is what AdSense sees, then of course he doesn't recognize it. Does anyone know what can I do in this case?? Or why is this attribute even there?? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to your website? But to make sure AdSense tag works correctly - check if there is "googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads" request in network tab. If it's present - tag works correctly and sends ad request.

Also, what exactly AdSense is telling you about code not being present? Note that if this is new account or site - it might some time (I'd say roughly a day) to recognize your site after you added the tag.

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem?

Comment: are you able to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer about the details of AdSense but I have had problems with meta tags in the head of HTML myself. Here's two possibilites to debug your code in regards to Gatsby:

1. Many plugins are disabled by default in development mode. Try `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` and then check if it works with plugins.
2. Use react-helmet to [place your script tag in the head of HTML](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-page-metadata/). Use `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` for testing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gatsby-plugin-google-adsense](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-adsense/) for displaying ads on your site.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is from [this](https://www.polynique.com/web-development/best-way-to-add-google-adsense-to-gatsby/) article, which suggest a simple React implementation of Google AdSense.

In your `gatsby-ssr.js` file:

```js
const React = require('react')

const HeadComponents = [
  <script
    src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXX"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
    async
  />,
]

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
  setHeadComponents(HeadComponents)
}
```

Then you create a Banner component to include in your Gatsby.js pages:

```js
const Banner: React.FC<BannerProps> = ({
  className,
  style,
  layout,
  format,
  client = 'ca-pub-XXXX',
  slot,
  responsive,
  layoutKey,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []
      adsbygoogle.push({})
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="banner-container">
      <ins
        className="adsbygoogle"
        style={style}
        data-ad-layout={layout}
        data-ad-format={format}
        data-ad-client={client}
        data-ad-slot={slot}
        data-ad-layout-key={layoutKey}
        data-full-width-responsive={responsive}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Full article [here](https://www.polynique.com/web-development/best-way-to-add-google-adsense-to-gatsby/).