# How to add Google Adsense to gatsby-ssr.js in Gatsby 3+ without modifying html.js?

Tags: gatsby, adsense

Looking for a way to add Google Adsense without [customizing html.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/). I've tried proceeding with Helmet with:

```js
<Helmet>
{process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ADSENSE ? (
  <script
    data-ad-client={`${process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ADSENSE}`}
    async
    src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
  ></script>
) : (
  console.log('Please add the env variable for Adsense')
)}
</Helmet>
```

but I run into the error:

> AdSense head tag doesn't support data-react-helmet attribute.

### Testing research after searching for resolution

#### gatsby-plugin-google-adsense

after install this throws an error that it isn't compatible with 3+ at time of writing this question, error message in terminal:

> warn Plugin @isamrish/gatsby-plugin-google-adsense is not compatible
> with your gatsby version 3.0.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.13.50

#### Add to Netlify

Searching the site I found this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57057872/1952287) that suggested to add during post processing but if I'm not using Netlify that really doesn't provide a solution.

#### Modify `html.js`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54294620/1952287) is an option if I were building before pushing source to the repository but I am not.

#### [Not able to connect AdSense to Gatsby blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420265/not-able-to-connect-adsense-to-gatsby-blog)

1. suggests the plugin I mentioned that throws an error in 3+
2. suggests add to html.js

At time of writing I'm unable to find a solution for Gatsby 3+. In Gatsby how can I add google-adsense to *gatsby-ssr.js* so that I can get adsense to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work for your use-case but here are some trials:

- Use [`gatsby-plugin-react-head`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-head/) which extends from [`react-head`](https://github.com/tizmagik/react-head/) but you may face the same incompatibility with `data-react-helmet` attribute.
- Use the [`gatsby-ssr.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/) API: `onRenderBody`, which exposes a `setHeadComponents` `props`:

  ```
  export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) =>
    setHeadComponents([
      <script data-ad-client={`${process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ADSENSE}`} async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"/>
  ]);
  ```

  *Note the ES6 naming*